# Architecture: multithreaded workers use synchronized processing method

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

I've got a processing class and a calculation class.

The processing object transmits the following arguments to a method in the calculation object:

- questions (type does not matter here)
- an `ExecutorService` object
- a self-reference

Within the calculation object, questions are solved in multiple threads by using the `ExecutorService`.
Whenever a result is obtained, a synchronized method from the processing object is called.

Is this architecture okay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than call a synchronized method, you are probably better off delivering the result to a [java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingDeque.html) that is a member of the processing object.

Then have the processing object remove results from the queue and process them at it's own pace.

Have a look at the [java.util.concurrent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) javadoc as well.

Comment: Okay, what I should have said: the result is of type java.sql.ResultSet. So I have to close the result after using it, which I guess is difficult when using a concurrent cue.

Comment: Then you need to explain what is happening in the synchronized method. You may experience database locking problems if you process the ResultSet in a synchronized method.

Comment: I am using .next() method for the results. All tables are set read only, so no modifications on the database could be done.

Comment: Either accumulate the "results" in a pojo and queue the pojo (which could be a collection object), or just queue the individual results if they can be processed in an interleaved way.

Comment: From my understanding, the ResultSet is only a cursor to the database. So I would have to go through the ResultSet and save all rows in a separate object, right? Is this really better style than just calling a synchronized method? In what circumstances could the database locking problems occur? I would say that in case the database is really locked, the thread just has to wait until it is open again.

Comment: Presumably you are using multiple threads because you're after performance. If you use that synchronised method then you're going to have contention for the instance lock (of the processing object) resulting in potentially many threads waiting to get access to it. Especially if you're doing something relatively slow like iterating through a ResultSet. Therefore, do the slow stuff in the same thread that runs the SQL query. If your tables are strictly read-only you may not have any locking problems, so I'd be more concerned object the contention problem to begin with.

Comment: Okay thanks for all the new hints. So you would say that the synchronized way is plain dangerous or just eventually not as performant? It seems to me that saving the whole ResultSet is not quite nice. But on the other hand I am not that experienced :).

Comment: If you're using the synchronised method then your entire processing object has to be carefully crafted to ensure that the final data structure that it's manipulating cannot be corrupted through other entry points. And it will most likely be slower as well.

Comment: In that case I'll give it a try! Thanks.